# overloading operator+ for std::strings - a bad idea?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

Now usually operator overloading should be used sparsely - in particular when it concerns stdlib.

Although Im curious what the pitfalls could be, if any, besides the obvious ones that the reader may not clearly see whats going on in code - is there any **technical** reason to refrain from this **particular** overloading ?

```
std::string operator+(const std::string& lhs, const std::wstring& rhs) {
    return lhs + to_utf8(rhs);
}
```

(also there is it's twin overload for doing the reverse transform)

I find this can make some operation easier to write out, eg.:

```
std::wstring{L"hel"} + "lo " + getName();
```

What are pros and cons, in particular do you see any scenarios (technical ones) where this could 'backfire' ?

Performance is not a concern.

Comment: You might consider tweaking the title. It makes the question sound more about opinion than it actually is and makes it sound like the question concerns the existing overloads, not this hypothetical one.

Comment: Do you also intend to place this overload in the `std` namespace ? Or your own namespace ?

Comment: This is dangerous.  What if I want the compiler to detect if some unaware programmer tries to concatenate a wide string and a std::string?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker -- putting it into `std` is not allowed. You can add overloads to `std` only if they involve a user-defined type.

Comment: @PeteBecker : I know - that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker -- don't set traps for people. If you see a potential problem, point it out.

Comment: @PeteBecker : I thought that's what I did - but clearly it was too cryptic.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that this isn't allowed (not sure it's allowed, either). But if it is allowed, I would stick this in it's own `namespace` to avoid surprising others. You can then pull the operator in with a local `using namespace` when you want to use it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux To my own surprise, [that doesn't really work either](https://godbolt.org/z/UnR2wh). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Using `using spooky::operator+;` seems to work. But I don't really understand why that works while `using namespace spooky;` doesn't. Edit : I hadn't noticed your answer, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do this, because it breaks Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL).

Consider this innocent test code:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    struct MyType {};

    MyType operator+(MyType, MyType);

    template<class T>
    auto doSomething(T t)
    {
        return t + std::wstring{};
    }
}
```

Doesn't look problematic, does it?

Well, it is:

```
void test()
{
    std::string s;
    myNamespace::doSomething(s);
}
```

> ```
> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' and 'std::wstring' (aka 'basic_string<wchar_t>'))
>         return t + std::wstring{};
>                ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> <source>:25:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'myNamespace::doSomething<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >' requested here
>     myNamespace::doSomething(s);
>                  ^
>
> <source>:12:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'myNamespace::MyType' for 1st argument
>     MyType operator+(MyType, MyType);
>            ^
> ```

https://godbolt.org/z/bLBssp

The problem is that your `operator+` definition is not found for the template. The `operator+` in the template is resolved via unqualified name lookup. This basically does two things:

1. Look for *any* `operator+` recursively in each enclosing scope until it finds the first one. If you define your own `operator+` for `std::string` and `std::wstring` at global scope, or in a different namespace, it cannot be found this way when there is *any* `operator+` "closer" to the template.
2. Look in the namespaces associated with the types of the arguments of the operator (ADL). Since both types are from `namespace std`, we look in there and find no `operator+` that works (see the other error notes on godbolt). You can't put your own operator there because that's undefined behavior.

Hence, the rule of thumb: Only overload operators that involve *your* types, because that operator must be placed in the same namespace as your types in order for ADL to work.

---

<sup>The issue is [the same](https://godbolt.org/z/PAhPOJ) even without the template, but in that case it may be reasonable to [pull in the operator manually](https://godbolt.org/z/Pth5CR). That's clearly unreasonable to require for generic code (which might not even be yours).</sup>

Comment: would a namespaced solution with local using declaring be a workaround ?

Comment: @darune If you mean [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/UnR2wh) then no. If you mean the one [mentioned](https://godbolt.org/z/Pth5CR) in my note at the bottom then yes. But do you really want to do that in every function? And are you really sure that you'll never rely on generic code that you can't modify and which simply won't find your operator?

Comment: I guess I could also make a string-bridge type and use when needed - that won't be nearly as 'spooky'

Answer (score 1):

I'd be concerned that your users may not realise they're using this functionality. Try to avoid implicit conversions like this.

It's easy to just write `to_utf8` when you need it.

If you have a big mix of `string` and `wstring`, fix it at source: convert to UTF-8 in `string` when you originally receive your wide strings, then all your strings "internally" are nice and consistent.